# More efficient way of editing images and displaying?

Tags: java, image

I'm making a Java application that prints an image and allows the user to edit it by drawing on it. Currently, my program listens for mouse dragged and once it is, changes the color of the pixel the cursor is currently on. In order to display the change, I call `paintComponent` at the end of each `mouseDragged` loop. Although its working as intended, the image flutters if I move the mouse too quickly.

Is this because I'm calling on `paintComponent` too many times? If so, how can I make my program work more efficiently?

I was thinking about simply editing the image in memory only and displaying the image every 1/30th of a second or so instead of displaying it after every edit.

Comment: "I was thinking about..." Yes do that. Or look into double buffering, but you're on the right path.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this because I'm calling on `paintComponent` too many times?

Once is too many.  Instead call `repaint()` & let it schedule (or ignore) the call to `paintComponent()`.